# How to filter a collection of beans using a collection of regex in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I want to autowire a collection of beans using `Spring` in annotaion mode. I've tried this something like the below ...

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mypkg", 
    includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = {"regex1", "regex2"}), 
    excludeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "regex3"))
public class BeanCollector {

    @Autowired
    private List<MyBean> myBeans;

    @Bean(name = "beans")
    public List<MyBean> getMyBeans() {
        return myBeans;
    }
}
```

This code works pretty well, but the problem is that in real world of my app. the `regexes` are generated in runtime, so I can't hardcode them as the code above. I used a class with a static method returning a String array like this ...

```
includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = Regexes.getIncludeRegexes())
```

But it brings compile error. I think it ought to have a solution but in spite of a deep googling I couldn't find any.

Any suggestion?

Comment: This approach (with the annotations and the `Regexes.getIncludeRegexes()` won't work, because the annotations in Java require compile-time constants for values of their properties, not **expressions**. You have to think about some Reflection-based approach, imho.

Comment: @kocko Thanks, I was in doubt whether the values of annotation's properties are processed in compile-time or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're wanting to dynamically select some set of the available beans that match the `MyBean` class/interface. The best way to do that is to inject a `Collection<MyBean>` as you're doing above and then iterate over the collection, selecting according to your criteria. Groovy closures, Google Guava, or Java 8 lambdas can make that process simpler to write.

Comment: I'm using iteration on autowired beans and filter desired beans now, but this method produce garbage (i.e. undesired beans will become garbage). This is why I'm looking for a way to avoid from creating undesired beans. Anyway, I'm curious to know that how iteration on a `Collection` can be done using `Groovy closures`, `Google Guava`, or `Java 8 lambdas`. Could you please give me a code snippet?

Comment: @faghani Then perhaps what you want is a factory or SPI instead, since your filter approach would still leave all the beans in the context (not even garbage, which doesn't matter).