# Limit a collection of autowired components using Package

Tags: java, spring, collections, filter, autowired

I am working on a project for parsing files that uses `Chains of Responsibility` of an abstract class called `EntityMapper` that are used for parsing. Currently we have 2 types of Files/Entities:

- `GrantEntity`
- `BillEntity`

All `EntityMappers` extend the abstract class:

```
public abstract class EntityMapper<T extends AbstractBaseEntity> implements Function<MapperExchange, T>
```

Soon we will have a `DonationEntity` that will represent a file that has some structural characteristics as `grantEntity`.

Instead of creating new classes of Type extends `EntityMapper<DonationEntity>` I wanted to ask if there is a way to filter an `@AutoWired` collection using `package names` or a `regex`.

Something like ?:

```
@Autowired
@ComponentScan("com.my.package.first,com.my.package.second")
private List<EntityMapper<GrantEntity>> entityMappers;
```

I unfortunately did not find an answer in the link below except to do it by hand and remove the elements from the collection:

- [How to filter a collection of beans using a collection of regex in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28557646/1688441)

Comment: No, there's no such thing in spring (everything is global), unless you start using child contexts. Remember to make the configuration as explicit as possible, as otherwise it becomes really difficult to navigate a codebase.

Answer (score 2):

You can use @Qualifer annotation to indicate logically similar components. Then specify a matching @Qualifier to the injection target. For example

```
class DependencyToInject{
}

@Configuration
public class AppConfig{

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("main")
    public DependencyToInject dependency1(){
       //return instance
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("main")
    public DependencyToInject dependency2(){
       //return instance
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("sub")
    public DependencyToInject dependency3(){
       //return instance
    }
}

@Component
public class DependentClass{

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("main")
  private List<DependencyToInject> mainList;

  @Autowired
  @Qualifier("sub")
  private List<DependencyToInject> subList;

}
```